# esp32 voltage divider readings off

Tags: esp32, voltage-divider

Trying to read from a voltage divider circuit using two 240 Ohm resistors.  Getting a reading of 6.0, when it should be 1.65.  Circuit is powered by a bench 3.3V and both the Huzzah32 and circuit are grounded.  Using USB for the Huzzah32. Any thoughts?

```
  void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() 
{
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A9);
  float voltage = sensorValue * (3.3 / 1023.0);
  Serial.println(voltage);
  delay(1000); 
}
```

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: Please add the schema.

Comment: My multimeter reads the correct Vout...

Comment: this gets me closer, but still low... float voltage = (sensorValue * 3.3) / (4095);

Comment: ESP32 chips have a problem with ADC and WIFI at the same time.  Maybe disable WIFI ?

Comment: `both the Huzzah32 and circuit are grounded` ... are the grounds joined? ... your schematic does not show a common ground

Comment: Some clarification: I picked A9 because it is a none-wifi pin.  In regards to common ground, my circuit drawing sucks.  They have a common ground.  The final answer is to subract .12 from my input values after multiplying by 3.3 and dividing the esp 12 bit increments (4095).  Thanks for input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ESP32 ADC is 12-bit, not 10-bit. therefore the formula should be:

```
float voltage = sensorValue * (3.3 / 4096.0);
```

Secondly, ESP32 ADC is not really linear, and tend to have lower reading than the actual value. You will need to do some calibration if you want to get a more accurate reading. You can take a look at my github on [esp32-adc-calibrate](https://github.com/e-tinkers/esp32-adc-calibrate).